# [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker or listener

Tags: ros, devel, rosrun, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I created two files with  name : talker.cpp and listener.cpp  and put them in path : catkin_ws1>src>beginner2_tutorials>src , and the chang the CmakeLists.txt as said in [11. Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++) ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) and then run `catkin_make` and then in root workspace run : `$ rosrun beginner2_tutorials talker`  but I receive this result :

[`rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/src/beginner2_tutorials`

I review [11. Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++) ROS tutorials] again i have noticed that i should have two executable in directory of my devel space but i havent any  executable file i have only pkgconfig and  beginner2_tutorials.pc !!! i dont know how should i have executable in located by default at ~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ , may be this is my problem so i couldnt run   `$ rosrun beginner2_tutorials talker` so please help me to solve this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222155/%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-talker-or-listener/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-12-08**:
The default location of the executable shouldn't be in your src directory if you're following the tutorials. Did you forget to source the setup.bash file from your devel directory?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-08**:
thanks , i am following the tutorials but where should be the executable ??? and what you mean about executable your mean is : the talker.cpp file? is its loacation in another place?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-11**:
i edited my question if you could please help me

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-12-11**:
hi,
when your using your own package called "beginner2_tutorials" i think you have completed the normal "beginner_tutorials" ? Is this so,and was the result, that you could run it ?

have you sourced your devel/setup.bash file before running rosrun ?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-11**:
yes i have run true my mistake was `catkin_make` and before this , i should make msg and srv folder.

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-11**:
thank you for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi , thanks for all helps all of my fault  was mkdir msg and srv so after make them and did the `catkin_make` again i could see

```
Linking CXX executable /home/fatima/catkin_ws2/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker
Linking CXX executable /home/fatima/catkin_ws2/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/listener
```

so two executable files with name talker and listener were made in catkin_ws2/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials
so when i run `rosrun beginner2_tutorials talker` again i could receive the result true
run `catkin_make` is so important .

---

Originally posted by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) with karma: 62 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [infinity_warp_101](https://answers.ros.org/users/52341/infinity_warp_101/) on 2020-03-08**:
I still didn't get you. I am having the same problem, and I am not able to resolve, can you elaborate on the steps?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this error may happen when you don`t grant an execute permission to the file

```
chmod +x exec_file
```

---

Originally posted by [tsadik](https://answers.ros.org/users/29582/tsadik/) with karma: 91 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on 2020-04-17**:
This solved it for me. Thnx